# How to divide an image according to its dimensions and get RGb color of each pixel

Tags: ios

If 110 X 110 dimension, editor generates pixel by pixel (COL X ROW) `rgb` color code starting from 0 to 109.

Example :

```
px0=,,,,,,,,,,,,e6ebf8,c6d1ef,b6c3eb,9fb1e5,a0b2e5,a1b3e6,8ba1df,869fdf,87a0e0,88a0df,8ba0e0,8da2e2,8ea3e2,8fa3e2,92a7e6,93a8e6,93a8e4,97abe8,9baaeb,9baaeb,9caaeb,9caaeb,9dabec,9eabed,9eaded,9dafed,9ab0e9,9aafe5,9cb2e6,9dafe1,9eafde,9eaed9,a0add7,a3add8,a2b2dd,a2b2df,a3b3e1,a4b4e1,a6b6e4,a7b8e4,a8b9e5,a9bae6,aeb9e6,afbae7,afbae8,afbbec,afbdf0,abbaf0,abbaf1,a9baf1,abbdf1,a7b9eb,a2b4e6,99aade,92a4d7,8ea0d1,8898cc,8898cb,8a99cb,8d9bcd,919ecf,909dcf,8d9bcc,8b99ca,8896c7,8693c4,8591c2,8391c0,8795c4,8c99c9,909ecd,93a0d0,95a3d2,99a6d7,99a7d6,97a6d4,98a6d7,96a3d4,92a0d1,909dcc,a1aad2,9aa4cb,959ec7,acb3d0,bdc2d8,e2e4ed,,,,,,,,,,,,|px1=,,,,,,,,,dce2f4,abbae6,8298da,7b93d9,7d95db,7f97dd,8098de,829add,839bde,839bde,849ddd,859ede,87a0e0,8ba0e0,8a9fdf,8ea3e2,90a2e2,8da0dd,9aadea,99ace7,96a9e3,a5b3eb,a1aee6,9eace4,99a6de,a1afe7,a1aee6,a0aee6,9eade4,92a5da,8b9ccd,8698c5,8490bb,737da2,7880a2,8286a4,888ba7,8990ac,8d96b2,949db9,969fbb,9ba4c0,9da6c2,,,,,,,,,|px2=,,,,,,,
```

and so on until `px109`

Comment: add some more detail with the question, and what you are trying to achieve,

Comment: i want to divide a image acc to its dimension and get RGb color of each pixel .